# how to suppress info messages for hadoop fs command

Tags: hadoop, suppressmessage

When we run hadoop fs -get command we see all the info messages. How can I suppress these messages.

```
17/12/05 17:59:02 INFO s3n.S3NativeFileSystem: Opening 's3://testbucketzs/Manish/test1/data/csv-serde-1.1.2-0.11.0-all - Copy (796) -
```

Comment: Change the `log4j.properties` for Hadoop

Answer (score 4):

If you don't want to globally change the log4j.properties for all the Hadoop processes, you can do a one-off command for

```
export HADOOP_ROOT_LOGGER="WARN,DFRA"
```

Then, following `hdfs` commands in that session will not output `INFO` messages.

Answer (score 1):

You need to modify the file as below :

`$HADOOP_HOME/conf/log4j.properties`
In this file, replace the following line:

`log4j.appender.EventCounter=org.apache.hadoop.log.EventCounter`

with this line:
`log4j.appender.EventCounter=org.apache.hadoop.log.metrics.EventCounter`

If you don't want to do that globally point the stderr to the black hole something like this `hdfs dfs -get /hdfs_path/ /local_path/ > 2>/dev/null`

Another suggestion use `hdfs dfs -get` instead of `hadoop fs` its deprecated.

This [link](http://hadooptutorial.info/suppress-warning-messages-in-hadoop/) has the explanation if you are interested.

Comment: I think one angle bracket was added by mistake. E.g. `hadoop fs -stat '%n' /path/* 2> /dev/null`